# Rabbitmq Queue is empty although there are messages in the queue

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm sending messages from Java Spring Boot application to consumer which is Python application.

Everything works fine except when I enter command `rabbitmqctl list_queues`  it shows that `video_queue 0` which means there are no messages in the queue.

Consumer is receiving messages and doing some long process; so if I send multiple messages in a row there should be some messages that waiting on the queue. Am I right?

Producer:

```
@Component
public class VideoProducer {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VideoProducer.class);
    private final static String BROKER_EXCHANGE_NAME = "video_exchange";
    private final static String ROUTING_KEY = "video_routing_key";

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private VideoService videoService;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    public void produceVideo(VideoDTO video) {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(BROKER_EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, gson.toJson(video));

        }
    }
}
```

Consumer

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channelConsumer = connection.channel()

# Video Consumer Settings
channelConsumer.exchange_declare(exchange='video_exchange',
                                 exchange_type='direct')
channelConsumer.queue_declare(queue="video_queue")
channelConsumer.queue_bind(queue="video_queue",
                           exchange="video_exchange",
                           routing_key="video_routing_key")


# Consumer Listener
def callback(ch, method, properties, body): 
   video_dto = eval(json.loads(body))  
   ##Something long process here
   print("Done..  ")    


channelConsumer.basic_consume(queue='video_queue',
                              auto_ack=True,
                              on_message_callback=callback)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channelConsumer.start_consuming()
```

Where can I see the messages on the queue that I declared? Because although I know there are messages on the queue I can't see them with the above command.

I am also using RabbitMQ management portal.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RMQ management console to view the the messages and other information of RMQ.
Consumers may consume more than one message and have them in the internal queue.To avoid this, set QOS to 1 and ack required to true.
More on QOS : https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Comment: I am also using RMQ management console but same. In the graph of queue that I'm sending multiple messages is still empty. I set in consumer basic_qos(prefetch_count=1). But still same. By the way my consumer is implemented in python.  Please see updated Screen shot.

Comment: I fixed it. Now my consumer only takes one message and until it finishes task on it the rest of the messages are waiting in the queue. The proper keyword as you said is QOS prefetch. But additionally I added `ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)` at the end of callback function. And I can see the waiting messages on the queue!

Answer (score 0):

You can check and manage the queues from your rabbitMQ Management porta accessing localhost:15672 and once any receiver has received the message from the queue it will automatically removed from the queue. So if you want to see your messages you better check it through the management portal and those messages will get remove once any reciever has received them.

Comment: I use rabbitMQ management portal also. I can see messages rates from the graphs but there is nothing in queues graph. The process in my consumer callback with message is long  so the rest of the messages should be waiting on the queue.

Comment: There will be a collumn in front of your queue name labeled as "incoming" (if i am not wrong) where you can see your messages and that collumn will show the number of messages in it as long as no receiver has received it

Comment: It's empty although message rates are showing the correct data.